# The requested page could not be found error appear in page but page is render correctly-drupal 7

Tags: 7

i had create one block in my custom module, which display in "CONTENT" region, only on "currant-trustees" page.

when i access url "localhost/drupal/currant-trustees" page is render correctly, but with error "The requested page "/drupal/currant-trustees" could not be found." and also page title is page not found.

Comment: have you created a page named as currant-trustees?

Comment: no i create block using template file

Comment: you have to create a basic page first named as current-trustees and then render the block in that page.

Comment: i mean first i register block using hook_block_info(), then register template using hook_theme() and finally assign content using hook_block_view() with template file.

Comment: page is rendered as per my requirement but problem is it display error page could not be found

Comment: yes as i told you need to create a blank page named as currant-trustees. you will not get this error and your block display in that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you only want to show said block on that page and nothing else. You might be better off implementing [hook_menu()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) to register a callback (a page) which displays custom content, instead of creating an empty page and showing a block on that.

It might look something like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function MYMODULE_menu() {
  $items['currant-trustees'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'MYMODULE_currant_trustees',
    'title' => 'Currant trustees',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}
function MYMODULE_currant_trustees() {
  $content = 'This is where your content should go, just copy the code from the block content';

  return $content;
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right when we wants to display only that block in page content region than your solution is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is i just registered block with specific page/url, but there is no any page/url on which drupal going to display block, so first i need to register page/url in drupal so create one page and than display block on that page.